# create a ksql table with a struct as the element type of an ARRAY from a stream

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

Hey i need help to create a ksql table with A STRUCT as the element type of an ARRAY.

Has everyone an idea.

This are Messages from the Input Stream:

```
{
  "GTIN": "4066136261834",
  "PRODUCT_SKU": "UC_55.08_W08_900_black",
  "SIZE_NAME": "34",
  "CALC_SALES_PRICE": 199.90,
  "SALES_PRICE": 199.90
}
```

```
{
  "GTIN": "4066136261846",
  "PRODUCT_SKU": "UC_55.08_W08_900_black",
  "SIZE_NAME": "36",
  "CALC_SALES_PRICE": 199.90,
  "SALES_PRICE": 199.90
}
```

The expected result of the KTable should be:

```
{
   "PRODUCT_SKU":"UC_55.08_W08_900_black",
   "variants":[
         {
            "GTIN":"4066136261834",
            "SIZE_NAME":"34",
            "CALC_SALES_PRICE":199.90,
            "SALES_PRICE":199.90
         },
         {
            "GTIN":"4066136261846",
            "SIZE_NAME":"36",
            "CALC_SALES_PRICE":199.90,
            "SALES_PRICE":199.90
         }
   ]
}
```

Comment: What query have you tried so far? What is the key of your table?

Comment: The key of the table should be the PRODUCT_SKU. I have tried the following:
   CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE MY_VARIANTSTABLE AS 
        SELECT
            PRODUCT_SKU,
            COLLECT_LIST(
                STRUCT(GTIN,SIZE_NAME,CALC_SALES_PRICE,SALES_PRICE)
            ) AS VARIANTS
        FROM MY_VARIANTS_STREAM
        GROUP BY PRODUCT_SKU
    EMIT CHANGES; 

I get an error message struct is not a valid function.

Comment: I believe you want `STRUCT<...>` since `()` create a function call, but you will want to refer to KSQL docs on proper syntax there. https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/reference/sql/data-types/#struct